# Cloud Functions for Firebase - How to stop writing to realtime database if value is too long

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I prevent writing to the firebase database if the value/string is too long ?

Ex: if I have this dataset

- userProducts

  - userId
  - productID

    - name
    - price

and I don't want to add this product to the database if the 'name' is longer than 10 characters. How can I do that ?

Like this:?

```
exports.preventNameTooLong = functions.database.ref('/userProducts/{userID}/')
.onWrite(event => {
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const product = event.data.val();
    if(product.name.length > 10){
        return;
    }else{
        return event.data.ref;
    }
});
```

Or is this code completely wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a realtime database rule for quicker validation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

In your case, add this rule:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 10"
```

This should go in your realtime database rules, so not in your function. This way the user can not even write to that path you inserted the rule in.

Comment: Ofc :D Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry for late answer ☺️